# htaccess rewrite question

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite the url http://mydomain/myapp/fakefolder to http://mydomain/myapp/index.php

I tried the following rule but thats not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fakefolder$ index.php
```

The .htaccess file is located inside myapp.

Kindly help

Thanks
vineet

Comment: First things first: Could you look in the appropriate file in your `sites-enabled` directory in your Apache config.   In there, make sure that `AllowOverride` is turned on for the site in question.  If it is not, your .htaccess will be ignored.

Comment: actually I tried the following rule RewriteRule ^index.php\/^fakefolder$ index.php and it works this way . so htaccess is not being ignored

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, your folder is not called `vineetstore`: it's called `fakefolder`.

---

The corrected rule works for me so I'd dare say your Apache installation is not configured to read `.htaccess` files in such location. You can easily test that: make a syntax error on purpose and see whether your site crashes.

Find your virtual host or site definition and make sure you have this directive:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: did you actually create the fakefolder in the root ? I actually want to avoid creating a folder and just rewrite the url to index.php. 
But in order to see if it works, I created the fakefolder directory and now it shows me 403 forbidden error.  Thanks

Comment: I reproduced your exact set-up in a name based virtual host. Have you made the test I suggested?

Comment: I got it now. Even I created a vhost and tried it. Changed RewriteRule ^fakefolder$ index.php to RewriteRule ^fakefolder$ myapp/index.php and it is working now. Thanks